# Регулярное выражение. Удалить все теги img не содержащие атрибуты width и height вместе

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо написать регулярное выражение, которое удалит теги img, у которых нет обоих атрибутов width и height.
Это регулярное выражение работает не стабильно:
/<img(?!.*width=).*?>|<img(?!.*height=).*?>/i
Пропускает некоторые теги.

Answer (score 0):

парсинг html при помощи регулярных выражений - плохой стиль. Лучше воспользоваться парсером, тем более это всего несколько строк кода

```
$html       = '<h3>
<img width="1" height="1">
<img width="1">
<img width="1" height="1">
<img height="1">
<img width="1" height="1">
<img >
</h3>';

$htmlDOM    = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDOM->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath      = new DOMXPath( $htmlDOM );
$imgs = $xpath->query( '//img[not(@width and @height)]');

foreach( $imgs as $element) {
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
}

echo $htmlDOM->saveHTML();
```

в результате получим

```
<h3>
<img width="1" height="1">
<img width="1" height="1">
<img width="1" height="1">
</h3>
```

Comment: тогда <\s*img(?=[^>]+width\s*=)(?=[^>]+height\s*=)[^>]+> - пробелы, табуляции и т.п. никто не отменял

Comment: а потом он напишет, что регулярка пропускает `src="xxx.jpg?width=1024"` или что-то подобное.

Comment: Переписал на domdocument